# If you blend copyrighted voices to create a unique voice, does the resulting creation become exempt from copyright restrictions?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, public-domain, artificial-intelligence, right-of-publicity

Suppose I blend copyrighted voices taken from popular media to craft an entirely distinct vocal composite.

For instance, combining snippets of various celebrity voices (like Leonardo Dicaprio and Mr. Beast) or iconic fictional characters (like Johnny Bravo and Popeye).

In either case, does the resulting creation, a distinctly new voice, become exempt from copyright restrictions?
Can I use these blended voices in my own creative projects and commercially benefit from their use?

Comment: Voices aren't copyrighted. Specific statements made, e.g., in a movie can be copyrighted, but not a general voice.

Comment: If I take half of Shrek and half of Cars, and mash together every second frame into a new movie, do I get sole copyright in the new movie? Well, maybe if the court says it's a non-derivative creative work.